# Correct way to simplify/neaten up complex or dense sequence diagrams

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I am creating a sequence diagram for an alarm system which involves a few different states and events which cause different behaviour depending on the state.

I am wondering the best way to present it. I planned on creating reference sequences to common events - such as entering a pin, a sensor going off and the alarm being activated - along the path of 'no fault'. This would be the alarm being off, being armed and then being turned off again. Without the alarm being set off by the sensors or pin entry failure.

Here's what I've got so far. Is there a better way (I will obviously define the reference sequences) or is this clear enough?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My approach to this is to keep sequence diagrams limited to a single level. The sequence diagram should only describe the behavior of one operation of one single class. To describe behavior of other operations of the same or other classes I use different sequence diagrams.

Furthermore I try to limit the number of messages in a sequence diagram to something like 15 or so. In general my rule is that I should always be able to print a diagram on A4 size and still be able to read it. If not there's too much on the diagram and it should be divided over several different diagram.

More details can be found here: [UML Best Practice: One Operation => One Sequence Diagram](http://bellekens.com/2011/05/27/uml-best-practice-one-operation-one-sequence-diagram/)